# web2py: getting field from rows object

Tags: python, web2py

The 'row' variable returns a single row but it appears the select statement returns a 'rows' object. I want to extract field a and field d from the 'row' variable.

I tried just doing row.a or row.d but this returns an error.

```
def d_comp():    

    c_id = request.args(0)
    evo_id = request.args(1)

    row = db((db.tbl_stat.c_id == c_id) & (db.tbl_stat.evo_type == evo_id)).select()

    c = db(db.tbl_c.id == c_id).select(db.tbl_c.ALL)

    a = 1

    d = 1

    p = 1

    return dict(c=c,a=a,d=d,p=p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question by doing the following inside the html file:

```
{{for val in row:}}
    {{=val.a}}
    {{=val.d}]
{{pass}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.select()` method always returns a DAL Rows object, even if it contains no records or just one record. The Rows object acts like a list, so you can extract individual records (which are DAL Row objects) by subscripting:

```
rows = db((db.tbl_stat.c_id == c_id) & (db.tbl_stat.evo_type == evo_id)).select()
row = rows[0]  # extracts the first record in "rows"
```

Another convenient method for extracting the first row specifically is:

```
row = rows.first()
```

The advantage of that method is that it simply returns `None` if there are no records in the Rows object rather than raising an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is put .first() after your .select()

```
row = db((db.tbl_stat.c_id == c_id) & (db.tbl_stat.evo_type == evo_id)).select().first()
```